# Get namespace of entity class in EF Core model builder

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I'm trying to establish a table naming convention such that the table name is a combination of the namespace and class.  For example

```
namespace Sales;

public class Order { }
```

would translate to a table name of `Sales_Order`.

I've worked it out for the individual class

```
builder.ToTable($"{typeof(Order).Namespace}_{typeof(Order).Name}");
```

I'd like to set this as a default for all tables, if a `ToTable` was not explicitly set.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    foreach(var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        if(entityType.ClrType == null) { continue; }
        {
            string tableName = entityType.GetTableName();
            string tableNamespace = entityType.GetType().Namespace;
            entityType.SetTableName($"{tableNamespace}_{tableName}");
        }
    }
}
```

but I can't get the namespace of the entity class. It is instead returning `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal`

My entities will be in multiple different class libraries so I'm hoping to intercept and change the name in the model builder.

Any suggestions on how to determine the namespace of the entity from within modelbuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entityType.GetType()` is [`GetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=net-6.0) method inherited from `object` so it  will return underlying type for `IMutableEntityType` (collection of which is returned by `builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()`), use `entityType.ClrType`:

```cs
string tableNamespace = entityType.ClrType.Namespace;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    foreach(var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        if (entityType.ClrType == null) { continue; }

        string entityName = entityType.Name.Split(".").Last();
        string tableName = entityType.GetTableName();

        if (tableName == entityName)
        {
            entityType.SetTableName($"{entityType.Name.Replace(".", "_")}");
        }

}
```

If the entity name matches the table name, the convention is applied.  If an explicit `ToTable` was used to apply a different name, the convention is skipped.